# How do I combine two or more confirmation dialog in a single confirmation dialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Here I have checked the sign of Issuance with Premium and wrote the confirmation dialog

[image]

Here I have checked the sign of claimhandling with premium and wrote the confirmation dialog

[image]

Needed: I need  both in a single confirmation dialog, not separately as mentioned in above pictures.

Here is my code:

```
if(issuance !=null && prem.compareTo(totalzero) == 1 && issuance.compareTo(totalzero) == -1) {
   ConfirmationDialog.showConfirmationDialog(this,
       "the value of issuance has a different sign to the sign of premium");
}
if(claimhandling !=null && prem.compareTo(totalzero) == 1 && claimhandling.compareTo(totalzero) == -1) { 
   ConfirmationDialog.showConfirmDialog(this,
       "the value of claimhandling has a different sign to the sign of premium");
}
```

If both "if" conditions are true then I need to get the both confirmation dialog into a single dialog.

Comment: Show us the code that displays those dialogs. **[edit]** your question. Do **not** post code in comments.

Comment: code still not added!

Comment: if(issuance !=null && prem.compareTo(totalzero) == 1 && issuance.compareTo(totalzero) == -1) { ConfirmationDialog.showConfirmationDialog(this,"the value of issuance has a different sign to the sign of premium");  if(claimhandling !=null && prem.compareTo(totalzero) == 1 && claimhandling.compareTo(totalzero) == -1) { ConfirmationDialog.showConfirmDialog(this,"the value of claimhandling has a different sign to the sign of premium");

Comment: oh God, @a_horse_with_no_name just told you to edit your question and add the code, **NOT** to add it as a comment !! seriously !!

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site.. Now I have added my code by editing my ques @Yazan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate the messages and make sure they are displayed as two line. 
I don't know what kind of Swing component your ConfirmationDialog is actual using, but most of the Swing text compontents support simply HTML tags for formatting, so the below example uses a `<br>` to create new line.

```
String message = "";
if (issuance !=null && prem.compareTo(totalzero) == 1 && issuance.compareTo(totalzero) == -1) {
  message = "the value of issuance has a different sign to the sign of premium";
}

if (claimhandling != null && prem.compareTo(totalzero) == 1 && claimhandling.compareTo(totalzero) == -1) { 
  if (message.length() > 0) {
    message += "<br>";
  }
  message += "the value of claimhandling has a different sign to the sign of premium";
}

if (message.length() > 0) {
  ConfirmationDialog.showConfirmationDialog(this, "<html>" + message+ "</html>");
}
```

Comment: Hi @ a-horse-with-no-name .. Your answer is perfectly right ..but how do I implement the same in case of ConfirmationDialog.. Here my ConfirmationDialog  extends JOptionPane class.

Comment: What do you mean with "implement in case of"?

Comment: Thank you @ a-horse-with-no-name

Comment: Thank you very much @ a-horse-with-no-name.. It worked for me .. No further doubts.

Comment: In case of appending three messages how do I do it?  (like if I am ought to check three variables )

Comment: Hi Can anyone help me with this issue:  If above mentioned  two conditions (answered by @ a-horse-with-no-name) are false then we will get empty confirmationdialog. How do I prevent it?

Comment: @Blessy: that's exactly what `if (message.length() > 0)` does

Comment: If  both conditions are false I am getting empty confirmation dialog..But I want to prevent it..How do I do it?

Comment: Then you remove that `if` condition when you copied my code.

Comment: The reason for getting empty confirmation dialog for me. I wrongly took String message = "  " instead of String message = "";